# define a F# function and avoid the return value

Tags: f#

define a function that has a single parameter of type string which which displayed on console. invoke the function passing it a message. ensure the function ignores any returned value

```
open System    
let NoReturnFunction msg =
    Console.WriteLine(string(msg))


NoReturnFunction "Hello World"
```

I am in a trouble to how to avoid return value of function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case there is no work to do because the `WriteLine` method doesn't return any values.  It's a `void` returning function.  In general though the way to ignore a return value in F# is to use the `ignore` function.

```
1 + 2 |> ignore
```

Couple of minor nit picks on the your code sample.  The first is you can avoid the cast to `string` by simply typing the parameter.  Second in F# it's more idiomatic to use the `printfn` function instead of `Console.WriteLine`

```
let NoReturnFunction (msg : string) = 
    printfn "%s" msg
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to annotate the type if you use `printf` because it is type safe.

Comment: Even simpler is: let noReturnFunction = printfn "%s"

Comment: @Lars, you should post that as an answer. People might miss that in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

For sake of completeness, you can also let F# infer the parameter type and the return type--like so:

```
let NoReturnFunction st = printfn "%s" st
```

This infers the type of s and the return type of NoReturnFunction (unit in this case).